# AJAX Call Returning "Undefined array key"

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

I cannot get my AJAX to work. Any help would be appreciated as I have spent hours on this with no avail. I am using test-data until I stop getting an error:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

My AJAX:

```
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'addsMeal.php',
                dataType:'json', 
                data: ({name: 'Emma'}),
                success: function () {
                    console.log("Sent data to addsMeal PHP file successfully.");
                }
            });
```

addsMeal.php:

```
<?php
    // topFields, newIngredient
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    echo($name);
?>
```

The error is:
Warning: Undefined array key "name" in C:\xampp\htdocs\GroceryListGenerator\Pages\addsMeal.php on line 3.

The console logs the data was sent successfully...

***Edit***

I ended up going with @ProfessorAbronsius solution below and altered my AJAX to his suggestion which keeps the data in the same file. His answer below worked seamlessly so now I have a running AJAX call and can plug my data into it now while testing it with the test he provided allowing me to see the data being captured on the browser.

Comment: The only way that could be happening is if you're also making a request to addsMeal.php which isn't being done via your ajax code

Comment: Are you sending and processing the request to/on the same page?

Comment: To expand upon what some may see as a somewhat cryptic comment above, if you are sending the ajax request to the same page that contains the PHP that processes that request and the PHP is as above ( with no logic to detect, differentiate and process between POST & GET requests  )  when the page is loaded initially using GET there can be no POST parameter `name` - hence error.

Comment: @ADyson I am calling it right below the AJAX call to open the page (for testing only): window.open('addsMeal.php', '_self');  Do you think that counts as calling it and is why I am not seeing the data when it redirects to that page?

Comment: @Professor Abronsius no, it is going to a different page, but maybe I should try doing it all on the same page.

Comment: `Do you think that counts as calling it `...yes of course it does - it sends a http request to the server to retrieve that page, which then causes the php code inside it to execute, just the same as when you request it via ajax

Comment: `why I am not seeing the data when it redirects to that page`...because that window.open command sends a GET request (not a POST) and because the data you sent in the ajax request isn't transmitted in this second request. They are completely separate http requests

Comment: `"maybe I should try doing it all on the same page...."` - there is no reason that you cannot send the ajax request to the same page but you do need to perform extra steps to ensure that the response is not tainted with HTML. Use the approach given below to send the response but you should call `exit` or `die` after sending said response. That said your issue is neatly explained above by @ADyson.

Comment: Thank you, everyone! I will approach the issue now that it is identified and will come back to update what the solution was. Thanks again!

Comment: I ended up going with @ProfessorAbronsius solution to keep the data in the same file. His answer below worked seamlessly so now I have a running AJAX call and can plug in my data while testing it with the test he provided seeing the data on the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying your PHP code to check if the 'name' key exists before accessing it:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        echo $name;
    } else {
        echo "No name parameter received.";
    }
?>
```

This will prevent the warning and handle cases where the 'name' parameter is not received properly.

Answer (score 0):

As a brief and quickly written example of a single page jQuery/PHP app perhaps the following might help clarify some of the points made above.

```
<?php
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    
    # logic test - only process ajax request if it is a POST request 
    # testing for key POST variables that you MUST have to contine 
    # makes sense.
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset(
        $_POST['name'],
        $_POST['colour'],
        $_POST['music'],
        $_POST['car']
    )){
    
        # ensure that no HTML before output 
        # is included in response
        ob_clean();
        
        
        # process AJAX request... do something interesting & send a response
        vprintf('The computer says: "<span>%s</span>" drove a "<span>%s %s</span>" 
        way too fast whilst listening to "<span>%s</span>" full blast', $_POST );
        
        /*
            update db, read from db, create images etc etc
        */
        
        # exit/die - ensure the whole HTML page 
        # does not become part of the response
        exit();
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Single page basic jQuery/Ajax to PHP script.</title>
        <script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js'></script>
        <style>
            div span{ color:red }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div></div>
        <script>
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                /* 
                    adding the `dataType:"json"` means you expect JSON
                    - which is fine but omitted here as response is
                    HTML
                */
                url:location.href,
                data: ({
                    'name':'Emma',
                    'colour':'bright red',
                    'car':'Jaguar XKR',
                    'music':'The Dead Kennedys'
                }),
                success:function(r) {
                    document.querySelector('div').innerHTML=r;
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Which outputs a nonsense string:

> The computer says: "Emma" drove a "bright red Jaguar XKR" way too fast
> whilst listening to "The Dead Kennedys" full blast

Comment: This worked great! I have my website now printing that I listen to The Dead Kennedys and while I did check out a song I'm going back to my other alternative rock music from the 2000s haha! Thank you!!!

Comment: Glad I was able to help illuminate things slightly for you and even better got you to listen to the DKs ;-)

Answer (score -1):

It seems like there might be an issue with how you're sending the data from your JavaScript to your PHP script. Let's modify your JavaScript code to send the data in a way that PHP can recognize:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'addsMeal.php',
                dataType:'json', 
    data: { name: 'Emma' }, // Change to object notation without parentheses
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log("Sent data to addsMeal PHP file successfully.");
                    console.log("Response from server: " + response);
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    console.error("Error occurred: " + error);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

addsMeal.php

```
<?php
    // Check if data is received via POST request
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        // Check if the 'name' parameter is set in the POST data
        if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
            // Retrieve the value of 'name' parameter
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            echo json_encode($name); // Return the name as JSON
        } else {
            // 'name' parameter is not set
            echo "Error: 'name' parameter is missing.";
        }
    } else {
        // Request method is not POST
        echo "Error: Only POST requests are allowed.";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Did you read any of the comments or the other answers? Did you actually test the OP's code vs yours. The brackets in the data notation, while redundant, will make no functional difference to what is sent from the client. That's nothing to do with the problem. Your answer notably doesn't explain why you think that was a problem? You've also made lots of unexplained adjustments to the php code. If you're going to change the code you need to justify it, otherwise it's just blind trust on the OP's part, and also smells of guesswork / cargo-cult code on yours. See also [answer]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).